# sort hashtable by values in ASC order

Tags: c#, .net, compact-framework

I am working in  compact framework 3.5

myfile.cs

```
public class Cases : IEnumerable
{
    private Hashtable cases = new Hashtable();   // hashtable initilized

    IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
            return cases.GetEnumerator();
    }

     public bool Add(string caseCode, string scanTime)
     {
        Reading reading = new Reading(caseCode, scanTime);
        cases.Add(caseCode, reading);   
        //some other logic          
     }
}
```

I have initialized the hash table as cases.I am adding the scan barcode in cases variable.Currently it is not in any order.I need to order the scaned barcode code in ascending order.How to do this.

**Update:**

For example i am adding the following items as below,

```
  Cases a = new Cases();
        a.Add("11115", "2014-09-11T01:55:25.0000000-07:00");
        a.Add("11111", "2014-09-11T01:55:40.0000000-07:00");
        a.Add("11112", "2014-09-11T01:55:45.0000000-07:00");
        a.Add("11110", "2014-09-11T01:55:56.0000000-07:00");
        a.Add("11113", "2014-09-11T01:56:10.0000000-07:00");
        a.Add("11111", "2014-09-11T01:56:17.0000000-07:00");
```

I want the data to be printed in same order as in list.Here the key what we are giving is time,here time is by default ascending order.But during printing this is printed like this,

```
[11110,StackOverflow.Reading] 
[11111,StackOverflow.Reading] 
[11111,StackOverflow.Reading] 
[11112,StackOverflow.Reading] 
[11113,StackOverflow.Reading] 
[11115,StackOverflow.Reading]
```

I want this to be print like this,

```
[11115,StackOverflow.Reading] 
[11111,StackOverflow.Reading] 
[11112,StackOverflow.Reading] 
[11110,StackOverflow.Reading] 
[11113,StackOverflow.Reading] 
[11111,StackOverflow.Reading]
```

Using Hash Table printing the above in random and not in any order.However SortedList is printing in ascending order.Can you tell me how to print the data in list in same order.

Comment: You should not be using `HashTable` unless you're working in .NET 1.0.  You should be using `Dictionary` instead.

Comment: This is in 3.5, not sure about the compact version though: System.Collections.Generic.SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>

Comment: That's the one I used in my answer. There's also SortedList which doesn't really differ much (it's explained in-depth on MSDN)

Comment: You just want it in the same order it was added?  That's not sorted, then.  Just use a List<T> and you're done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`Dictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.90).aspx).

The below program achieves your desired behavior - sorting by `Reading.scanTime`.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace StackOverflow
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Cases a = new Cases();
            a.Add("keyA", "01:00");
            a.Add("keyB", "11:30");
            a.Add("keyC", "06:20");
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Reading> x in a)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", x.Key, x.Value);
            }
        }
    }

    public class Cases : IEnumerable
    {
        private Dictionary<string, Reading> cases =
            new Dictionary<string, Reading>();

        IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return cases.GetEnumerator();
        }

        public bool Add(string caseCode, string scanTime)
        {
            Reading reading = new Reading(caseCode, scanTime);
            cases.Add(caseCode, reading);
            cases = cases.Values.OrderBy(v => v).ToDictionary(r => r.caseCode);
            return true;         
        }
    }

    public class Reading : IComparable
    {
        public string caseCode; // don't mind public fields and bad naming, it's just an example ;)
        public string scanTime;
        public Reading(string a, string b)
        {
            this.caseCode = a;
            this.scanTime = b;
        }

        public int CompareTo(object obj)
        {
            Reading other = obj as Reading;
            if (other == null)
            {
                return -1;
            }

            return this.scanTime.CompareTo(other.scanTime);
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return caseCode + " scanned at " + scanTime;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: SortedDictionary is not in my dll.SortedList is there and I tried your example with SortedList instead of SortedDictionary ,i am getting this error "Error 1 'Handheld.Kitting.myfile.SortBarCodeAscending' does not contain a definition for 'Compare'"

Comment: I have to look into accessibility level of this method I posted in the exa ple. I'll get back to you.

Comment: Hello again. I posted a full runnable example. It works for me in Visual Studio 2010. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: It should be 100% compatible with compact framework now. I used `SortedList` instead of `SortedDictionary` for this purpose.

Comment: I testing in console.It is sorting key in ascending order.Is it possible to sort the Value in ascending order.Please see my update in question.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion i made,Please see my update in question.I tested your answer which is working correct as per my first request .

Comment: So you want it sorted by the `scanTime` of `Reading`, am I right?
Your updated example is confusing, because the first `Case` has time `2014-09-11T01:56:25` which should not be the first when we sort by time. Please double-check your example. I'll get back to this question later, right now I'm very busy at work

Comment: Yes,need to sort it by scanTime of reading.Your understanding is correct and thanks for your prolonged help.

Comment: Fixed. Try it now. Another (slightly more flexible) solution is to sort while getting the enumerator (using `yield return` and `OrderBy`). It is the faster solution if `Add` operations clearly outnumber `GetEnumerator`. Otherwise, the above is just fine.

Comment: Working as expected.Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

The items in a `HashTable` are inherently unordered.  You cannot order them.  You'll need to use an orderable collection if you want to have the items in a particular order.  You can take the items from the collection order them, and put them somewhere else, but it won't affect the hash table itself.

Comment: Is any way to sort the data in HashTable.Can you please tell me an example of the way you explained in your answer.

Comment: @user2681579 The whole point of my answer is to state that you can't.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SortedDictionary`. If I am not mistaken the default sorting is ASC. But you should consider performance (search time and memory use) aspects too. Have a look on [DotNetPerls](http://www.dotnetperls.com/sorteddictionary) or [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c(v=vs.110).aspx) articles.

Comment: SortedDictionary is not available in my dll,instead SortedList is there.Any idea how to do with SortedList.